# Get archive of user's post by month Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, archive, author

I'm in the process of developing a site that will have multiple authors, and have so far been successful in creating an author template that shows posts by a particular author.

The next thing I'd like to do is show the archives for that particular author listed by month in the sidebar. It would work in the same way as wp_get_archives() but would return only the author's posts, rather than every single post ever made.

Are there any built in WP functions that could help me?

Cheers

Comment: Ok. No responses yet, but I'm going down the route of using;
    add_filter(getarchives_where)

Answer (score 0):

So I finally came up with a solution. It's probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but I'd love to know if anybody has a better way. :)

I basically figured out that WP is able to retrieve an archive of the user's posts through the url like http://mysite.com/?author=2.

From there it was just a case of figuring out how to get the author's ID to append against the url.

```
<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>

    <?php
    if(is_author()){ ?>
        <h3>ARCHIVES</h3>
        <ul>
        <?php
        $archives = wp_get_archives('type=monthly&echo=0');
        $archives = explode('</li>',$archives);
        $links = array();
        foreach($archives as $archive){
            $url = preg_replace("/<a href='(.+)' title='(.+)'>/", "<a href='$1&author={$curauth->ID}' title='$2'>", $archive);
            echo $url.'</li>';
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

By all means, feel free to pick apart if there's a better way.